# how to write testcases for yaml file using python

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

Can someone help me write the test case for the YAML file using python.

config.yaml

Environment: dev

```
AthenaCred:
  AthenaDatabaseName: dap_cred
  AthenaTblName: athena_prod
  AwsSecretKey:  null
  AwsAccessKeyId: null
  S3StagingDir: 's3://aws-athena-query-results/'
  RegionName: 'us-east-1'
```

load_rule.yaml

```
Insert:
  - compute: 25:adobe:redshift
    entity: marketing
    group: '87:count'
    name: Test rule 1
    product: adobe
    query: SELECT count(*) "count" from public.dual
  - compute: 25:adobe:redshift
    entity: marketing
    group: '0:default'
    name: Test rule 2
    product: adobe
    query: SELECT count(*) from public.dual

Delete:
  rule_id:
    - '107:test'
    - '2:test'
```

Comment: Hi supriya and welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and to this guide on [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you please show what have you already tried to solve this problem? Also, please wrap your code with ```, so that it gets rendered properly.

Answer (score 0):

> one way

```
import sys
    import load_rule.yaml

    yaml_str = """\
    Get_Request:
      alias : 'amway1'
      session_url : 'url2'

    Post_Request:
      alias : 'amway2'
      session_url : 'url2'

    yaml = load_rule.yaml.YAML()
    try:
        data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

> another way

```
import yaml

file_name = 'load_rule.yml'

with open(file_name) as infile:
    data = yaml.load(infile)

person = data['Person']
person['name'] = input('What is your name? ')
person['age'] = int(input('What is your age? '))
person['nationality'] = input('What is your nationality? ')
person['footed'] = input('What foot? ')
person['position'] = input('What is your position? ')

with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(data, stream=outfile, default_flow_style=False, indent=3)
```

here you can modify poython code as per your need after opening yaml file inside python saving data into array. take object query and perform test tasks.

Comment: Thanks Harsh, i will take as reference.

Comment: @supriya if it may help you can up vote or mark it as answer if works fine. otherwise comment for more help. that's how it works